# Moving files between Libraries along with Lookup Columns?

Tags: lookup-column, library, move

Is it possible to move a file from one library to another along with the lookup columns associated with it?

Comment: If the destination library have the same lookup, it should be possible. Try it out and see what happens.

Comment: how are you trying to move the file between libraries, using Rules, workflow or send to location?

Comment: I am currently trying sent to location only, see we are basically sending the file... but I want its look-up column to go along, how is it possible using workflow. Can u give an example for "action"/"step" ? For Example consider a resume (as a file) and its Job-Id against which the resume is applied, now I shortlist the resume for interview... so I moved it to Shortlist Library, but how do I retain the JobID look -up ?

Comment: @BennySkogberg: I have same look -up there, still no help. Because logically also .. we are moving a file only, I want to know.. how can we move the look-up along with it, we right click on file and use send to option, whether we use email or copy option...it will only deal alone with that file... I want columns to move with it :-(

Comment: @UmeshSharma What happens if you download from source and upload to destination? Are the lookup functioning then?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Finally I figured out :-) 
See while making a workflow, there is option of "Association Columns" there we can add new column and select the type as "Look-up",search for the specific column name and save it. 
Now just save and publish the workflow !! And it finally works. Revert, for any clarifications.[image]